# Java Inheritance Base Class uses Derived Class Method

Tags: java, inheritance

Recently I stumbled upon Java tests and found a strange behaviour.

```
class MainOne {
    
    private int i = 5;
    
    public MainOne() {
        System.out.println("MainOne says that I is " + getI());
    }
    
    public int getI() {
        System.out.println("MainOne getI was used");
        return i;
    }
    
}

public class TheTest extends MainOne {

    private static int i = 10;
    
    public TheTest() {
        System.out.println("TheTest says that I is " + super.getI());
    }
    
    
    public int getI() {
        System.out.println("TheTest getI was used");
        return i;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheTest test = new TheTest();
    }
    
}
```

Result was:

> TheTest getI was used
>
> MainOne says that I is 10.
>
> MainOne getI was used
>
> TheTest says that I is 5

Question is, what happened? How come Base class uses it descendant's method?

Comment: What do you mean? They are called in the constructors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all about order of execution and constructor inheritance. `TheTest` constructor implicitly calls the `super` `MainOne` constructor.

so

```
public TheTest() {
    System.out.println("TheTest says that I is " + super.getI());
}
```

calls

```
public MainOne() {
    System.out.println("MainOne says that I is " + getI());
}
```

which calls the overriden `getI()` because of polymorphism.

```
public int getI() {
    System.out.println("TheTest getI was used");
    return i;
}
```

The `i` here is the `static i` declared in `TheTest`. Finally

```
super.getI());
```

gets called which uses `MainOne`'s `i`.

You therefore get

```
TheTest getI was used

MainOne says that I is 10.

MainOne getI was used

TheTest says that I is 5
```

Note that polymorphism does not apply to fields and that fields (whether `static` or instance) may hide fields of the same name in parent classes.

Comment: But how did polymorphism kick in? Base class should not know about its derived class at the time it invoked getI() method.

Comment: @Rofgar The base class doesn't know, but the JVM does. This is a result of late binding.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you. Still this is a tricky situation.

Comment: @Rofgar Consider reading up on polymorphism and how it is implemented. You can start [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200115/what-is-early-and-late-binding) for some details on late binding.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important points to note in this problem.

1. super.getI() invocation inside `MainOne`

   ```
   public TheTest() {
       System.out.println("TheTest says that I is " + super.getI());
   }
   ```

   forcefully this invocation goes to super class even though the method is overridden.
2. Field `i` in subclass is defined as a `static` field

   There is a difference in the results based on whether this field is a static or not. When the overridden `getI()` is invoked from `TheTest` constructor, the invocation goes to the `MainOne` classes method. However when this invocation happens, instance fields of `TheTest` class is not yet initialized to the assigned values (but only default values).

   If the field `i` in `TheTest` is a instance field, `getI()` will print 0 instead of 10.

   Details of the sequence of invocation is hard to represent here. However in case you wanted to find further details, please refer below.

   ```
   new TheTest()
       -> super() - implicitly invoke default constructor
           -> inside MainOne() constructor
               -> System.out.println("MainOne says that I is " + getI());
                   -> this results in a getI() invocation
                   -> since getI() is overridden by subclass
                   -> invoke on TheTest instance, not MainOne class.
                   -> TheTest's instance fields not given the assigned values
                   -> TheTest's static fields have got the assigned values
               <- string concatenation completes for System.out.println()
           <- MainOne constructor (or the super) is completed
       <- super() completes

       -> System.out.println("TheTest says that I is " + super.getI());
           -> this results in a getI() invocation
           -> however explicit super.getI() forcefully goes to super class
           -> invoke on MainOne (super) instance, not TheTest class.
       <- string concatenation completes for System.out.println()
   <- new TheTest() constructor completes
   ```

Hope this helps you in understanding the details further.